# How to draw dual axes in ggplot2？

Tags: r

I am a novice. I am trying to draw a two-coordinate line chart in which the abscissa represents D, the left ordinate represents R, and the right ordinate represents M and A. My data set and code are below, and I want to control the left vertical axis The range of coordinates is (0.9-1.0), and the right is (0.1-0.5), how can I do this?

```
data<-data.frame(R=c(0.9649789,0.9700804,0.9632690,0.9523244,0.9339738),
             M=c(0.2465927,0.2263204,0.2520991,0.2982259,0.3614747),
             A=c(0.1427684,0.1428706,0.1642165,0.1937662,0.2353444),
             D=c(20,15,10,5,2))

p2<-ggplot(data,
           aes(x = D,y=R))+
     geom_line(color="#6FB585")+
     geom_point(size=3,color="#6FB585")+
     scale_y_continuous(name = 'R',
                 sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.25, name = 'M and A'))+
     geom_line(aes(y=M,x=D), color="#E8BF80")+
     geom_point(aes(y=M, x=D),size=3,color="#E8BF80")+
     geom_line(aes(y=A,x=D), color="#A8BF85")+
     geom_point(aes(y=A, x=D),size=3,color="#A8BF85")
```

Comment: Your data do not have `MAE` and `tuneLength`

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother you, MAE=M, tuneLength=D.I read your suggestion, but my data doesn't start from the same point, is there any other solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean here. You may want to experiment with various values,  such as changing all 0.875 to 0.85 or some other values.

Comment: ohhhh，it’s my fault, i got it

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I really don't know what to do anymore. Now, I have another question, how to add a legend to this picture, I tried to use scale_color_manual(), but it didn't work......

Comment: It’s difficult to understand and answer a question in comments. You are likely to get some answers if you post a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something to start with:

```
ggplot(data,
           aes(x = D,y=R))+
    geom_line(color="#6FB585")+
    geom_point(size=3,color="#6FB585")+
    scale_y_continuous(name = 'R',
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.-0.875)/0.25, name = 'M and A'))+
    geom_line(aes(y = M*0.25+0.875, x= D), color="#E8BF80") +
    geom_point(aes(y=M*0.25+0.875, x=D),size=3,color="#E8BF80")+
    geom_line(aes(y=A*0.25+0.875,x=D), color="#A8BF85")+
    geom_point(aes(y=A*0.25+0.875 , x=D),size=3,color="#A8BF85")
```

[image]